# ForeignKeyField subclass python_value not observed after Model.create

Tags: python-3.x, peewee, hashids

Curious about a behavior I'm trying to add on top of Peewee's `ForeignKeyField`. I've subclassed it to use the `Hashid` library to provide an obscured `hashid`, instead of the raw Integer, to anything dealing with the model objects (say, for serialization with an API).

Storing and retrieving objects (rows) seems to go fine, but when using `ModelClass.create` to make a new object/row, I find that `id` on the object is the `int` value, and not the output of the `hashid` encoding.

The question is this: **how can I get the new model instance to report the hashid-encoded id in the id field after creation, instead of the raw int?** Is it a bug in peewee where it should be using the `python_value` function, or is this expected behavior? Is it not recommended to subclass `PrimaryKeyField`?

Here is some code to demonstrate:

```
from peewee import PrimaryKeyField
from hashids import Hashids

class HashidPrimaryKeyField(PrimaryKeyField):
    hashid = Hashids(min_length=16)

    @property
    def prefix(self):
        return self.model_class.__name__.lower() + '_'

    def db_value(self, value):
        try:
            return self.hashid.decode(value.replace(self.prefix, ''))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return super().db_value(value)

    def python_value(self, value):
        hashed = self.hashid.encode(value)
        return self.prefix + hashed


class User(BaseModel):
    id = HashidPrimaryKeyField()
    first_name = TextField(null=False)
    last_name = TextField(null=False)
    email = TextField(null=False, index=True)
    password = TextField(null=False)

    class Meta:
        database = SOME_DATABASE


u = User.create(first_name="Foo", last_name="Bar", email="foo@bar.com", password="some salt/hashed password")
print(u.id) # Prints: '1'

u2 = User.get(User.id == u.id)
print(u.id) # Prints the nicely-formatted hashid: "user_4q2VolejRejNmGQB"

assert(u == u2) # Fails.
```

Comment: Hello? Anybody? Bueller?